# Eclipse closed suddenly, and not opening

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am working on a project in my INDIGO IDE for past 10 hrs, that all at a sudden it got closed and now not starting.

Can't find out what went wrong with my IDE.

Can anyone tell me what is the error and help he recover?

Log:

```
!SESSION 2013-06-30 13:41:52.720 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_30
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2013-06-30 13:41:54.233
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-06-30 13:43:51.488
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (36).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/ProjectVariableProviderManager
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPathVariableManager.<init>(ProjectPathVariableManager.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPathVariableManager(Resource.java:2025)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileStoreRoot.createStore(FileStoreRoot.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.initializeStore(FileSystemResourceManager.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMetaInfo(SaveManager.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMetaInfo(SaveManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1527)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2251)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectVariableProviderManager
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/ProjectVariableProviderManager
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPathVariableManager.<init>(ProjectPathVariableManager.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPathVariableManager(Resource.java:2025)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileStoreRoot.createStore(FileStoreRoot.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.initializeStore(FileSystemResourceManager.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMetaInfo(SaveManager.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMetaInfo(SaveManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1527)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2251)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectVariableProviderManager
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-06-30 13:43:51.512
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (36).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/ProjectVariableProviderManager
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPathVariableManager.<init>(ProjectPathVariableManager.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPathVariableManager(Resource.java:2025)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileStoreRoot.createStore(FileStoreRoot.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.initializeStore(FileSystemResourceManager.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMetaInfo(SaveManager.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMetaInfo(SaveManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1527)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2251)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectVariableProviderManager
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Try to start eclipse with the [-clean](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm) flag. (_Cleans cached data used by the OSGi framework and Eclipse runtime. Try to run Eclipse once with this option if you observe startup errors after install, update, or using a shared configuration_)

Comment: @FrVaBe~ My entire system failed, after that. Anyways thanks for you feeds. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're missing some files in the eclipse installation. Maybe they were deleted, but it is throwing a lot of `NoClassDefFound` errors. Try backing up your data then re-installing eclipse.

Comment: not files are missing. As I said it was working perfectly before an abrupt close. Re-installation is always the last-resort, but as of now trying to figure out the issue.

Comment: I think you would spent more time debugging this issue than if you would simply use another eclipse installation. From the error it clearly seems, as already suggested by @imulsion, some eclipse jars have been removed.

Comment: ok guys thanks for the help. Problem found: My entire hardware failed. System not starting! Thank you very much

Comment: @imulsion Why should this answer be accepted if the cause of the problem was another? I grant you the reputation but that would make no sence!